# facebook api - get likes and number of comments made for a specific period

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am pretty new to Facebook api's and would like to know if it's possible to fetch the number of likes and also the number of comments for any specific page for a given period of time via the api?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `FQL`:

e.g.

```
select comment_count, share_count, like_count from link_stat where url = "http://techcrunch.com/2011/04/12/facebook-comments-now-on-over-50k-sites-get-more-social-with-latest-upgrade/"
```

you can use this api explorer as your reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=select+comment_count%2C+share_count%2C+like_count+from+link_stat+where+url+%3D+%22http%3A%2F%2Ftechcrunch.com%2F2011%2F04%2F12%2Ffacebook-comments-now-on-over-50k-sites-get-more-social-with-latest-upgrade%2F%22

Comment: Thanks Newbie! , Is it possible for me to add a time filter to the query? that is, could I specify the date range?

Comment: It is possible but it depends on the table you are using if there is able field you want to use for filter.

you can read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

this might help

you can upvote and accept my answer if this is helps you. Thanks